# Get the memory usage of a process in windows in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, windows, memory-management, process

Is there any way i can get the memory usage for all processes currently running on a machine in vb.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to look into [Performance Counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx).

- [An Introduction to Performance Counters](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/perfcounter.aspx)
- [Changing and Retrieving Performance Counter Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s155t6ta%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)
- and this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679962/what-is-the-correct-performance-counter-to-get-cpu-and-memory-usage-of-a-process)( you will have to convert to Vb.net)