# Performance Counter to get CPU and Memory Usage of a Process

Tags: vb.net, performancecounter

Firstly, I'm working on Visual Basic
With Ref. to this pre-posted thread [What is the correct Performance Counter to get CPU and Memory Usage of a Process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679962/what-is-the-correct-performance-counter-to-get-cpu-and-memory-usage-of-a-process)

I wanted to get the cpu and memory used by a particular process in a label or listbox, let's say i want to get the processor % time of notepad.exe

Actually i am making a MYSQL Oriented tool that connects to MYSQL and i want to record how much CPU Consumption is actually caused to make the whole process happen. So i need to add the CPU and Memory consumptions of few particular processes concerned that i can see in task Manager.

So i want to supply the names of all the processes in code and get the output.

I need to figure this out using performance counter for one process and rest i can make out.

Thanks a lot for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You migh want to consider using this:

```
Dim cpu as New System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter()
With cpu
    .CategoryName = "Processor"
    .CounterName = "% Processor Time"
    .InstanceName = "MyProcess"
End With

cpuLabel.Text = cpu.NextValue()
```

Note that this can quickly become quite heavy on the processor itself if doen for multiple processes. For an alternative take a look at [How To Get Hardware Information](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17973/How-To-Get-Hardware-Information-CPU-ID-MainBoard-I). Its in C# but should be relatively easy to convert to VisualBasic.NET either manually or using [this tool](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Since the topic is about VB.NET, I can direct you outside of StackOverflow to VBForums, on [this thread](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?898060-RESOLVED-VS-2019-General-Question(s)-IDE-Environment&p=5597893&viewfull=1#post5597893).

Be aware of tha VS2019 and newer PerformanceCounters does not cover *CategoryName*, *CounterName* and *InstantName* as comboboxes anymore, **intentionally**. You have to code instead.

For a basic CPU/RAM meter - which supports for almost all type of machines - you may use the following:

```
Public Class Form1
Private pCPU As New PerformanceCounter
Private pRAM As New PerformanceCounter
Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        pCPU.CategoryName = "Processor"
        pCPU.CounterName = "% Processor Time"
        pCPU.InstanceName = "_Total"
        pRAM.CategoryName = "Memory"
        pRAM.CounterName = "% Committed Bytes In Use"
        pRAM.InstanceName = ""
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Try 'RAM
        Dim RAMpercent As Single = pRAM.NextValue
        Label1.Text = RAMpercent.ToString
    Catch ex As Exception
        Label1.Text = "ERROR"
    End Try
    Try 'CPU
        Dim CPUpercent As Single = pCPU.NextValue
        Label2.Text = CPUpercent.ToString
    Catch ex As Exception
        Label2.Text = "ERROR"
    End Try
End Sub
```

End Class