# How to calculate % CPU Utilization using PerformanceCounter Class?

Tags: c#, .net, performancecounter

I been looking at [PerformanceCounter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter) for monitoring system performance. I have figured out how to call built in counters. What I'm struggling with is understanding the values that I get back and how compare those values to what I can see in Task Manager.

So far I have successfully been able to monitor available RAM in MB and it correctly corresponded to value in Task Manager.

first I created PerformanceCounter

```
 myMemoryCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes", true);
```

Then I put the following line inside a loop.

```
Console.WriteLine("Value" + myMemoryCounter.NextSample().RawValue.ToString());
```

When looking at counters for processor, I'm not able to make connection to % CPU Utilization that can be observed in Task Manager.

Do I need to have multiple counters and compute the value or is there easier way?

Update:

Looking at question [What is the correct Performance Counter to get CPU and Memory Usage of a Process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679962/what-is-the-correct-performance-counter-to-get-cpu-and-memory-usage-of-a-process) it just describes which counter to use but not how to convert results to percentage?

`NextSample().RawValue` returns long data type and I need to know how to convert it to percentage.

Using the following code

```
 var _myCPUCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
 Console.WriteLine("CPU " + _myCPUCounter.NextSample().RawValue.ToString("0.000"));
```

I get this value  `1794607539062` how do I convert that to percentage?

Comment: I have updated the question. The problem with duplicate there is nothing about how to get percentage value, only which counter to use.

Comment: This counter's result is already a percentage...

Comment: `NextSample().RawValue` returns LONG data type, for example in my case one value was `1794607539062` how do I convert that to percentage

Comment: But wait, in your code you're using the `Available MBytes` counter - how is that related to CPU usage??

Comment: I was first trying to get it to work with `Available MByte` and it returns correct value. The problem is with `"% Processor Time"` that returns some value that I'm not sure how to convert to percentage.

Comment: Have you [checked this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679962/what-is-the-correct-performance-counter-to-get-cpu-and-memory-usage-of-a-process)?

Comment: I already linked in my question. That is where I got the code `("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total")`

Comment: You're retrieving the NextSample which gives you the "raw, or uncalculated, value".  But a percentage is a calculated value.  Why don't your use NextValue() instead of NextSample and let the counter do the calculation for you?

Comment: @FrankBoyne thanks, that is what I needed. Is there a formula for calculating that value out of raw value?

Answer (score 2):

```
// TRY THIS
public class MyCPU
{
    // This method that will be called when the thread is started
    public void Info()
    {
        /*
         * CPU time (or process time) is the amount of time for which a central processing unit (CPU) was used for processing instructions of a computer program or operating system
         */
        PerformanceCounter cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
        for (int i64 = 0; i64 < 100; ++i64)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CPU: " + (cpuCounter.NextValue() / Environment.ProcessorCount) + " %");
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, your solution was just what I needed. I made a couple minor changes so I could get the average over a few seconds you can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40949924/nextvalue-returns-0

Answer (score 0):

According to the source, for the CPU counter, which is type `Timer100NsInverse`, the calculator method returns:

```
(1f - ((float)(newSample.RawValue - oldSample.RawValue))/(float)(newSample.TimeStamp - oldSample.TimeStamp)) * 100.0f;
```

Note it needs two samples.

See `CounterSampleCalculator.cs` which you can find in multiple places on the web.  It can show you all the calculations for all the types.  But you can just call the `Calculate` methods, or `NextValue()` as already described.