# VB.Net get CPU Usage of Program

Tags: vb.net, cpu

Is it possible to get the CPU Usage of the own Program that you are running in VB.Net?
I would like to add a CPU detection, in case the CPU of the Program is above for example 10% it increases a timer deleay to reduce the CPU.

Comment: Look at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4679962/2557263). While it's for C# and for an arbitrary process, it's trivial to convert its answers to VB.NET and to your own process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this.
There is a mix of informations had by `Process`, `PerformanceCounter` and `Computer`.
Putting together those informations you can get information by your process in relation con SO memory usage.
Also by `Process` you can get other informations about your app like max cpu usage, time usage etc.

```
    Using currentP As Process = Process.GetCurrentProcess

        Dim bFactor As Double = 1000 / 1024
        Dim cMemory As Long = New PerformanceCounter("Process", "Working Set - Private", currentP.ProcessName).RawValue
        Dim sbInfo As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder

        sbInfo.AppendLine("Current ProcessName    : " & currentP.ProcessName)
        sbInfo.AppendLine("Current WorkingSet     : " & (cMemory * bFactor * 0.000001).ToString & " MB ")
        sbInfo.AppendLine("In a total system PM   : " & (My.Computer.Info.TotalPhysicalMemory * bFactor * 0.000001).ToString & " MB ")
        sbInfo.AppendLine("Percentage of all      : " & ((cMemory / My.Computer.Info.TotalPhysicalMemory) * 0.01).ToString("N6"))

        'MsgBox(sbInfo.ToString)
        Console.WriteLine(sbInfo.ToString)
    End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

First declare a PerformanceCounter

```
Private CPUPerf As New PerformanceCounter()
```

then initialize it to get CPU info

```
    With CPUPerf
        .CategoryName = "Processor"
        .CounterName = "% Processor Time"
        .InstanceName = "_Total"
    End With
```

then you can access the value

```
    CPUPerf.NextValue
```

See [PerformanceCounter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.performancecounter?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) for more information.

Comment: So I would use 'MessageBox.Show(CPUPerf.NextValue) to show the CPU Usage of the Program? It says 0 to me but the Program has a CPU Usage of 4.2%.

Comment: Sure.  Measuring usage is not precise and will be based on when the sample is taken.