# !vmstat command output - what does Private memory area mean?

Tags: .net, memory-leaks, windbg

One of my .NET process that interops with native dlls is throwing an OutOfMemory Exception. Following is out put of !vmstat command

```
> TYPE                      MINIMUM                      MAXIMUM                      AVERAGE  BLK COUNT                        TOTAL  
~~~~                      ~~~~~~~                      ~~~~~~~                      ~~~~~~~  ~~~~~~~~~                        ~~~~~  
Free:  
Small                          4K                          64K                          57K      4,545                     262,979K  
Medium                        68K                         960K                         425K        240                     102,000K  
Large                      1,084K                       1,084K                       1,084K          4                       4,336K  
Summary                        4K                       1,084K                          77K      4,789                     369,318K  

Reserve:  
Small                          4K                          60K                           6K        515                       3,255K  
Medium                        72K                       1,012K                         982K        863                     848,287K  
Large                      1,864K                      15,756K                       7,801K         11                      85,819K  
Summary                        4K                      15,756K                         674K      1,389                     937,363K  

Commit:  
Small                          4K                          64K                           6K      8,762                      55,669K  
Medium                        68K                       1,024K                         436K        455                     198,651K  
Large                      1,028K                      21,168K                       4,702K        114                     536,079K  
Summary                        4K                      21,168K                          84K      9,331                     790,401K  

**Private:**  
Small                          4K                          64K                           6K      3,267                      22,087K  
Medium                        68K                       1,024K                         945K      1,008                     953,539K  
Large                      1,864K                      19,008K                       6,245K         52                     324,775K  
**Summary                        4K                      19,008K                         300K      4,327                   1,300,402K**  

Mapped:  
Small                          4K                          64K                           4K      4,190                      18,728K  
Medium                        68K                       1,004K                         498K         21                      10,467K  
Large                      1,028K                      11,536K                       4,443K         10                      44,435K  
Summary                        4K                      11,536K                          17K      4,221                      73,632K  

Image:  
Small                          4K                          64K                           9K      1,820                      18,107K  
Medium                        68K                         980K                         286K        289                      82,931K  
Large                      1,032K                      21,168K                       4,010K         63                     252,687K  
Summary                        4K                      21,168K                         162K      2,172                     353,726K
```

As you can see that Private summary Total is 1.3GB. What exactly Private mean here? Does it mean native memory or managed memory area? Any links for description will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Private Bytes" is memory allocated by this process that can't be shared with other processes. (In a .NET app, this will include both native allocations and the managed heaps.)

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984186/what-is-private-bytes-virtual-bytes-working-set/1986486#1986486) gives an excellent description of the different "types" of memory.