# What type of memory has 2 GB limitation on 32-bit Windows?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, memory

When using Windows 7 32-bit, most applications cannot go beyond 2 GB limitation (due to things like addressable size, licensing, etc.).

When running Visual Studio on a 32-bit OS, it usually starts throwing OutOfMemoryException when the Working Set goes up to 1.8 GB. This probably due to physical memory fragmentation.

What exactly does this 2 GB limitation refer to?

Is it Working Set, Private Working Set, Private Bytes, Committed Size (Virtual Size), or a commbination of something else?

Also, if you want to check whether an application can potentially run into the 2 GB limitation, which type of memory should you pay attention to?

Here is a post that is similar to my memory question:

[What is private bytes, virtual bytes, working set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984186/what-is-private-bytes-virtual-bytes-working-set)

Answer (score 2):

32-bit windows applications have a 2GB Virtual Address space limitation ([this can sometimes be extended to 3GB by setting some OS boot time switches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487508)). This is sometimes referred to as  Virtual Bytes as per the question you link to.