# bad_alloc thrown with 4Gb of Standby on Windows

Tags: c++, windows

I have a program that has been throwing a `std::bad_alloc` consistently. The platform is Windows 8 x64, and is being compiled with ICC without optimizations.

I have noticed that the exception is thrown when the amount of "Free" memory hits 0, but there is still about 4Gb of "Standby" memory remaining. Based on what I know, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089638/what-is-the-standby-list-in-windows-memory-management) answer, I had thought that when free memory was depleted, standby memory would be used. This does not seem to be occurring.

The problem does not seem to be caused by a single large allocation. The exception is consistently thrown during deep recursion, so the allocation in question has already been done numerous times. The stack looks like this during the throw:

```
    KernelBase.dll!_RaiseException@16()    Unknown
    msvcr110d.dll!_CxxThrowException(void * pExceptionObject, const _s__ThrowInfo * pThrowInfo) Line 152    C++
    msvcr110d.dll!operator new(unsigned int size) Line 63   C++
    Project2.exe!list_make(int elt, void * list) Line 85    C++
    Project2.exe!`anonymous-namespace'::ReverseHelper(void * list, void * reverse) Line 225 C++
    Project2.exe!`anonymous-namespace'::ReverseHelper(void * list, void * reverse) Line 227 C++
    Project2.exe!`anonymous-namespace'::ReverseHelper(void * list, void * reverse) Line 227 C++
```

The size passed to `operator new` is only `12`. Any ideas of what could be causing this behavior?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about windows 8 but on all previous versions operator new has some internal state tracking but then calls ::HeapAlloc() which when out of space calls ::VirtualAlloc(). So as far as any Win32 application is concerned there is no such thing as "Free" memory and "Standby" memory as VirtualAlloc() will allocate pages even if there isn't free ram available (it works on pages). This is all deep implementation details though and the exception being thrown is being thrown from operator new(), so the issue could entirely be in the MSVCRT's implementation of operator new.

Comment: Can you show us the minimum amount of code that can replicate the behavior?

Comment: Is this a 32 or 64 bit build? A 32bit application in a 64bit environment is still a 32 bit application (and they have their own memory limits)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas This is a x86 build, but I don't think I'm going over the limit. The `bad_alloc` is thrown when about `1,200,000` KB are allocated. To be sure, I wrote a test program also built for x86 to leak memory, and it got up to `2,100,000` KB, and didn't throw when it used all the free memory.

Comment: @AdamSchnitzer: 2Gb is about the limit in 32bits without tweaking the OS/build system. That does not explain the exception at 1.2Gb though

Comment: Concluding that "1,200,00 KB are allocated" is dangerous.  You see the working set first, not the commit size.  Working set will be well below the commit size when the program has been running for a while and pages were swapped out.

Comment: @HansPassant According to Windows resource manager, both my commit and working set are about `1,200,000`KB. I agree that it is certainly a dangerous amount of memory, but this is a stress test, not normal memory usage. Switching to x64 is not an option due to target limitations.

Comment: @AdamSchnitzer, the utilities that come with windows are not very good at describing total virtual memory allocated by a program. Commit size = amount paged to disk, Working set = amount in ram. But adding these two together does not = total amount allocated by process. For example: right now TaskMan says communicater.exe has Working Set of 35MB, Commit Size of 97MB but Process Explorer shows a total Virtual Size of 328MB. I believe this is because pages that have not yet been accessed count towards Virtual Size but not towards Commit. Empty pages still count against your max virtual alloc tho

Comment: @NtscCobalt Got it. Perhaps I just have a bunch of empty pages because of the recursion? So it's likely Im actually going over the limit, but windows just isn't showing it? If that's the case, I can go ahead and close the question. I appreciate the help

Comment: @AdamSchnitzer, more likely you are actually allocating all of the available space since you said you have 1.2GB of Commit and 1.2GB of Working Set. You likely have no more virtual address space for your process. If you open it up in Processes Explorer and show Virtual Size it is probably >2.4GB which is close to the limit even with the /3GB compiler switch.