# Freeing memory allocated to a 2-dimensional vector

Tags: c++, memory, vector

I have the following 2 dimension vector:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> m_scoreVector;
```

I try the following code to free the allocated memory. But, it does not work. Just a small portion of memory will be releases:

```
for (int k = 0; k < m_scoreVector.size(); ++k){     
    std::vector<int>().swap(m_scoreVector[k]);
    m_scoreVector[k].shrink_to_fit();   
    m_scoreVector[k].clear();
}

std::vector<std::vector<int>>().swap(m_scoreVector);
m_scoreVector.shrink_to_fit();
m_scoreVector.clear();
```

I am new to memory management. Please let me know how should I free the allocated memory for this vector. 
Thanks.

Comment: It's freed for you. It's really that simple.

Comment: It is not! At each run, this vector gets 2000 KB but it only frees 200 KB!

Comment: How are you determining how much memory is being used?

Comment: I am debugging the program and checking the Task Manager!

Comment: Is there any way to completely remove it?

Comment: @Bipario Try running your piece of code that you suspect may have a memory leak 10,000, 100,000 or 1,000,000 times. Then if there's a memory leak you'll know because it will add up that much.

Comment: @ Patashu: Thanks for your answer. But I did and it really is not any memory leak ! I am so confused!

Comment: @Bipario, Look up RAII. That's how we roll.

Comment: @Bipario This might shed some light on your confusion - *There is more than one way to ask 'How much memory is a process using?' and they all mean very different things.* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984186/what-is-private-bytes-virtual-bytes-working-set

Answer (score 0):

Vectors manage the memory for you. They will free the memory when they go out of scope. In general, if you don't allocate memory with new or malloc, you don't need to worry about freeing it either.

Answer (score 0):

swap() and shrink_to_fit() are two ways to free vector memory,you can not use it together

try this code:

```
for (int k = 0; k < m_scoreVector.size(); ++k){     
    m_scoreVector[k].clear();
    m_scoreVector[k].shrink_to_fit();   
}
m_scoreVector.clear();
m_scoreVector.shrink_to_fit();
```

Comment: I tried `m_scoreVector.clear(); m_scoreVector.shrink_to_fit();` without that for loop，it works the same.