# Strange behavior: Number of pointers Vs Private bytes

Tags: c, windows, pointers, memory, memory-management

I am writing a server component on 32 bit Windows (Windows XP). I've lots of allocations, de-allocations and re-allocations in the code. I kept this component running for hours then brought it down. I found lot of memory (Private Bytes) was still allocated to the process  (I use SysInternals Process Explorer to monitor private bytes)

Definitely there were no memory leaks in the code. So I investigated further and came up with this piece of code that reproduces exact same behavior.

```
#define NUMBER_OF_POINTERS 1000

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char* ptr[NUMBER_OF_POINTERS] = {} ;
    int len[NUMBER_OF_POINTERS]={};
    printf("\nCheck private bytes now and press a key to go on realloc");
    _getch();

    printf("\nRandomly allocating/reallocating memory. Press x to stop...");

    while(1)
    {
        int random_kilobytes = rand() % 7 + 1;
        int randomindex = rand()%NUMBER_OF_POINTERS;
        int size2increase = random_kilobytes*1024;

        assert (len[randomindex]+size2increase > 0);

        char* reallocated = (char*) realloc(ptr[randomindex], len[randomindex]+size2increase);

        if (reallocated)
        {
            ptr[randomindex] = reallocated;
            len[randomindex] += size2increase;
        }

        if ((_kbhit()) && (_getch()=='x'))
            break;
    }

    printf("\nPress a key to free allocations");
    _getch();

    for (int i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_POINTERS; i++)
        free(ptr[i]);

    int _heapmin_ret = _heapmin();

    printf("\n_heapmin returned %d", _heapmin_ret);

    printf("\nCheck private bytes now and press a key to exit");
    _getch();

    return 0;
}
```

In this code I go on allocating and reallocating memory chunks of increasing size to set of pointers. My findings is:

**Memory hold in the form of private bytes at the end of process, is directly proportional to the number of pointers and number of allocations re-allocations made to it.**

Details:

1. If we have many number of `NUMBER_OF_POINTERS` (e.g. 1000) and we allow this code to run till it goes beyond 1 GB 
   and then if we `free` allocations, we'll find lot of Private Bytes still allocated (ranging from 15 MB to 40 MB)
2. If we have very few `NUMBER_OF_POINTERS` (e.g. 1) and and we allow this code to run till it goes beyond 1 GB (May be we need to increase `size2increase` to make it faster) 
   and then if we `free` allocations, we'll find very few Private Bytes still allocated (few kilobytes)

Any explanation to this behavior?

Comment: You are looking at a statistic that says how much *virtual* memory your process uses.  It is just a number, it has nothing to do with how much physical memory you use.  Releasing an allocation doesn't reduce the number, the released block of address space simply gets added to the list of free blocks.  To be reused by a future allocation.  Getting the number to shrink requires the happy and unlikely coincidence that an entire range of address space becomes unused.  It is best to stop staring at numbers that just don't mean much.  One GB of VM is no problem.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984186/what-is-private-bytes-virtual-bytes-working-set. "none of these values are a reliable indicator of how much memory an executable is actually using, and none of them are really appropriate for debugging a memory leak."