# What is PrivatePageCount in Win32_Process?

Tags: c#, windows, wmi

`PrivatePageCount` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/CIMWin32Prov/win32-process) says:

> `PrivatePageCount`
>
> Data type: uint64
>
> Qualifiers: MappingStrings ("Win32API|Process Status|SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION|PrivatePageCount"), DisplayName ("Private Page Count")
>
> Current **number of pages** allocated that are only accessible to the process represented by this Win32_Process instance.

But inspecting the ManagementObjectSearcher values, it looks like the same value as `PageFileUsage`, but in bytes instead of kilobytes.

```
using (var items = new ManagementObjectSearcher(String.Format("Select * From Win32_Process")).Get())
{
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var PageFileUsage = (UInt32)item["PageFileUsage"]; // kb
        var PrivatePageCount = (UInt64)item["PrivatePageCount"]; // same as PageFileUsage?

        Debug.Assert(PageFileUsage == (PrivatePageCount / 1024));
    }
}
```

Multiplying this value by the system's page size (`Environment.SystemPageSize`), gives a value in terabytes, but it is not close to Virtual Memory (address space).

Could the documentation be wrong and `PrivatePageCount` be equivalent to `PageFileUsage`?

Comment: _[Somewhat helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984186/what-is-private-bytes-virtual-bytes-working-set)_

Comment: Yes, the documentation is wrong.  Unit is bytes, not pages or kbytes.  I suspect the author of the article got mislead by the property name, don't we all.