# Memory Consumption for IIS vs. Task Manager

Tags: iis, iis-8

I have a discrepancy on a Windows Server (2019 DC) that is showing up as follows:

**[image: IIS stats]**

[image: Task Manager Stats]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L44WT.jpg)

Which one is correct? The site eating 13GB in IIS is showing 8GB in Task Manager.

Does IIS do something that's not apparent in Task Manager?

Comment: In Task Manager you can right click on the column header and choose "Select columns" to enable more columns. That will lead you one step closer to what you are looking for, but be prepared to learn the terms on memory https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984186/what-is-private-bytes-virtual-bytes-working-set

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to remove IIS and remove it again unter the roles?